# Run Python Library as script

Tags: python, installation, pip, pdfminer

Some important background upfront, I am using a computer that does not give me access to pip. In fact I do not have access to the command prompt. This make is it impossible for me to install additional libraries unfortunately (at least the standard way).

My question is whether I can run a python library without formally installing it. Could I download the library, and then store it the same directory as my main script, and then import it like I would with a multi `.py` script project with functions being defined in other files, almost as if I had written the script natively on my computer?

Specifically, I would like to use pdfminer.six. Apparently it is written completely in python, however, I realize that may not mean what I think it does. It may be similar to numpy which I understand has C++ code associated with it.

Comment: Are you able to run any `.py` file that you write? Using `os.system(...)` you could just make calls to `pip` or run a `python setup.py install` command for the package that you need

Comment: Also, jsut out of curiosity, in which context are you given a computer to code python but are not allowed to install libs or use the command line?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I appears that when using a command such as `os.system('pip install pdfminer.six')` it fails to install`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:`. To be brief, its a secured computer. Most useful scientific packages are preinstalled, but anything outside of them is appearing to be out of reach without going through a lengthy approval process.

Comment: Try to do `os.system("pip install  --trusted-host pypi.python.org pdfminer") `

Comment: @FlyingTeller thanks for your suggestion, however I get the same error I was previously running into.

Comment: You can place the [`pdfminer`](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/tree/master/pdfminer) folder from [`pdfminer.six` repository](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six) and can directly import the functions like done in the [`command line tools`](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/tree/master/tools) and it should work, given that you can meet the other dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use a web-based-interpreter solution like Google Colab and work in your browser.

https://colab.research.google.com

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32448925)

Comment: Hey. I have linked directly to Google Colab, the service I am recommending. So, if the link becomes invalid, then the service no longer exists, and any information I provided in the answer will also be invalid, anyway.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have edited my answer to indicate that there may be other, similar solutions, should Colab disappear.

Comment: Why on earth would you vote this down? 

Answer (score -1):

You can import any script or lib from your current folder ([example](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/914803590588158032/1006678105177468958/unknown.png?width=735&height=702)). You can find any lib you want by googling 'lib_name github'. Download the zip and unpack it in your folder, it should work.
You can also go to your python Lib folder on another computer and copy libs from there (By default: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib)

Comment: This is wrong. You cannot just download any python package from github, extract it into your folder and it works. A good example would be any library that needs to compile C code. You would also need to install dependencies and the github might not actually be organized the same way than what ends up in `site-packages` after installation

Comment: @Michael I made an attempt at this. I ran into dependency issues as @FlyingTeller pointed out. For example with `pdfminer.six` it needs the `cryptography` library installed. I tried a similar process but it isn't working and doesn't throw an error even. That might be the end of the road for this approach without a deeper knowledge of how libraries work. But thank you!